# Error expected a ';'

Tags: c++

I have the following code, an error `IntelliSense: expected a ';'` is reported at the line indicated:

Comment: http://ideone.com/Z12Mca full code.

Comment: Double click on the error and it will take you to the line where it occurs.

Comment: Neither does your link give access to "full code", nor did you show a testcase (http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @VusP: This is not needed in C++.

Comment: if its Intellisense's error than just rebuild your project..

Comment: Context is everything, and you have removed it!

Comment: I added the required context - offsite posting of code is unnecessary and unhelpful.  The question and the answers need to be able to stand-alone.

Comment: First: Please **edit** your question to add further detail. Second: Please see [mcve]. Third: Code should not be provided as a link - if at any rate - possible. Please add the code to the question with the correct formatting (four spaces in front of each line).

Answer (score 11):

Your actual code is like this:

```
Dictionary::Dictionary() {
    ...

    Word* fromRecord(const string &theWord,
        const string &theDefinition,
        const string &theType)
    {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

In other words, you define a function *within* a function. This is not allowed.

Comment: +1 I would rather say *define*.

Comment: @AliAlamiri A constructor is a normal function, it's just named after the class and doesn't have a return type.

Comment: @AliAlamiri:  You may need to elaborate on that comment; what are you trying to say?  It is a constructor yes, but that does not make a nested function declaration valid - this is not Pascal!

Comment: @Clifford No I didn't say it would make it valid. It's just it may confuse the OP when the answer says function instead of constructor. Some people don't realize that a constructor is a special type of function.

Comment: @Ali: I see.  Your original comment was terse to the point of complete ambiguity.  I agree with Joachim.  The point is that nested functions are not allowed, had he said that a *"function within a constructor"* was disallowed, that would have been too specific suggesting that in other cases it was allowed.  I find it unlikely that many programmers that have *written* a constructor would not have understood that it is a specialised function.

Comment: And the reason the compiler recommends adding a `;` is that the closest thing to legal C++ it could think of is that you are trying to declare an external function followed by a block statement, and external function declarations end with a semicolon.

Answer (score 1):

I was missing a semicolon

```
struct Node {
    int data;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
};  // <---------- was missing a semicolon here

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
```

Adding a semicolon solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I assume fromRecord is either a function call or constructor. So you are missing a colon before opening a new scope

```
Word* fromRecord(const string &theWord,
    const string &theDefinition,
    const string &theType); <- Here
```

If your intent is to create an inner function then look at lambdas.